# Psycopg2 - Connect to postgreSQL database using a connection string

Tags: python, psycopg2

I currently have a connection string in the format of:

```
"localhost://username:password@data_quality:5432"
```

What is the best method of using this to connect to my database using psycopg2? e.g.:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(connection_string)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could make use of [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse), creating a dictionary that matches psycopg's connection arguments:

```
import psycopg2
from urllib.parse import urlparse

conStr = "localhost://username:password@data_quality:5432"
p = urlparse(conStr)

pg_connection_dict = {
    'dbname': p.hostname,
    'user': p.username,
    'password': p.password,
    'port': p.port,
    'host': p.scheme
}

print(pg_connection_dict)
con = psycopg2.connect(**pg_connection_dict)
print(con)
```

Out:

```
{'dbname': 'data_quality', 'user': 'username', 'password': 'password', 'port': 5432, 'host': 'localhost'}
<connection object at 0x105f58190; dsn: 'user=xxx password=xxx dbname=xxx host=xxx port=xxx', closed: 0>
```

Answer (score 3):

Documentation for pyscopg2 `connect` is [here](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect). Following their syntax you connect like this:

```
connection = psycopg2.connect(host='localhost', user='<username>',
                              password='<password>', 
                              dbname='data_quality', port=5432)
```

If you are using Windows, it can be stupid about resolving `localhost` if you don't have a network connection. You can get around this by instead using `'127.0.0.1'` for `host`